# Whitelist specific USB keys and block others

Tags: group-policy, usb-storage, restrictions

Im looking for a solution to implement and easily manage USB white-listing in multiple countries.
We have restricted USB storage usage using group policies, as 99% of users don't need to use external storage, but we are having problem with 1% of users. This 1% uses specific USB keys, which contains e-signatures and other certificates issued by local government to access e-services (e.g. tax offices). We have no control over these storage's, but there's clear business requirement for them.

Anyone can suggest solution, how to white-list these different type of USB devices, while blocking others, keeping in mind, that we don't control them and they are different in each country?

Comment: Write custom udev rules.

Comment: You will have to get device IDs or similar for those devices as otherwise you will not be able to whitelist individual devices. Some of them might be an independent class.

Comment: You can't do this reliably, because it's actually pretty trivial to fake USB ID's (you can do it with about 20 USD of hardware and a few hundred lines of code.